# yum update on CentOS 6.6 fails

Tags: centos, yum

I have CentOS 6.6 running on VirtualBox w/ NAT.  I am behind a proxy and have configured my proxy settings; the virtual machine is talking just fine to the internet.

When I attempt to install anything via yum, or do a yum update, I receive the following error:

```
# yum update
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror, refresh-packagekit, security
Setting up Update Process
Determining fastest mirrors
epel/metalink                  | 6.0 kB 00:00
 * epel: dl.fedoraproject.org
 * extras: linux.cc.lehigh.edu
 * updates: centos.sonn.com
base                           | 3.7 kB 00:00
base/primary_db                | 4.6 MB 00:00
file:///var/ftp/pub/repos/OS/CentOS/6.6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] Could not open/read file:///var/ftp/pub/repos/OS/CentOS/6.6/x86_64/os/repodata/repomd.xml
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: centos-base.  Please verify its path and try again
```

The path in /var/ftp/... didn't exist, so I created it but the only change is that the error switches from being a file access error to an error saying that the repomd.xml file is damaged.  If I try to `yum install <package>` where I `--disablerepo=<every repo except epel>`, it succeeds.

Anybody have an idea of what's happening here?

Answer (score 2):

Your CentOS was configured with a local repo. You'll have to edit your repositories in `/etc/yum.repos.d`. [Here](http://wiki.centos.org/PackageManagement/Yum/Priorities) is a sample for `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-bas.repo`

Answer (score 1):

Clean up the metadata files (all of the `repomd.xml` files):

```
# yum clean metadata
```

and try again. It also looks like at one time you may have made a local copy of the packages in `/var/ftp`. Check your `/etc/yum.repos.d/CentOS-Base.repo` file to confirm it's looking to the Internet for packages. The file should have something like this for at least `[base]` and `[updates]`:

```
[base]
name=CentOS-$releasever - Base
mirrorlist=http://mirrorlist.centos.org/?release=$releasever&arch=$basearch&repo=os
#baseurl=http://mirror.cc.ltgc.com/centos/$releasever/os/$basearch/
gpgcheck=1
gpgkey=file:///etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-CentOS-6
```

Note that the `mirrorlist` line in not commented.

Comment: I've tried cleaning up the metadata; no luck.  My CentOS-Base.repo file looks exactly like your sample above, but it is still looking locally for the repo.  Is there maybe a more global configuration that is overriding the repo settings?

Comment: Check /etc/CentOS-Media.repo. Confirm the enabled line has "enabled=0".

Comment: Yes, it has "enabled=0".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to the other posters for giving me the heads up that it was looking for a local repository; it turns out the EPEL repo configuration was (for some reason) set up to override the centos-base repo configuration with a local file path.  I removed this and now everything works fine.