# CentOS 8: GPG check FAILED errors on sudo yum update

Tags: centos, yum, system-installation, gpg

Immediately after an install from a verified ISO of CentOS 8.0.1905, I logged on as root, enabled the network, logged off; logged in as the user created in installation, and and ran `sudo yum update`. No plugins are loaded.

Many many errors followed regarding the GPG key, so I ran `sudo yum clean all` , `sudo yum clean metadata` , and `dnf clean all` then ran `sudo yum update` again with the same failure

Have not created local copies of packages or used a local repo which eliminates [yum update on CentOS 6.6 fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/220407/yum-update-on-centos-6-6-fails)

/etc/yum/pluginconf.d/fastestmirror.conf was empty which would seem to negate [CentOs 5.3, Yum Update Fails](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/252954/centos-5-3-yum-update-fails) as a source of solutions.

Comment: Why didn't I describe the GPG errors? Accidentally deleted them.

Comment: Centos 8 As I know is EOL since 2021, better use Rocky Linux or Oracle Linux

Answer (score 2):

Since the error discussed a GPG key, renamed the two GPG keys in /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/ to add **.bad** at the end, hoping to get a new GPG key.

Repeated `sudo yum clean all` , `sudo yum clean metadata` , and `dnf clean all` , then ran `sudo yum update` again and it tells me it can't open /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial

Renamed the keys by removing the .bad suffix. Reran `sudo yum update` and was prompted to accept the keys. I did, and the update succeeded.

Answer (score 1):

I ran

```
rpm --import /etc/pki/rpm-gpg/RPM-GPG-KEY-centosofficial
```

then reran `sudo yum update`.